# ZIP operator doesn't work with PublishSubject, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new in RxJava and can't realize – why my "zipped" observable doesn't emit items when I use two PublishSubject with it? (As far I know ZIP operator should "merge" two stream into one)

```
val currentSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
val maxSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

currentSubject.onNext(1)
maxSubject.onNext(2)

currentSubject.onNext(1)
maxSubject.onNext(2)

Log.d("custom", "BINGO!")

val zipped = Observables.zip(currentSubject, maxSubject) { current, max -> "current : $current, max : $max " }
zipped.subscribe(
    { Log.d("custom", it) },
    { Log.d("custom", "BONGO!") },
    { Log.d("custom", "KONGO!") }
)

currentSubject.onComplete()
maxSubject.onComplete()
```

I'm expecting the items are showed up in "{ Log.d("custom", it) }" function, but it's not happens. What I'm doing wrong?

Log after compile:

2019-06-25 22:25:36.802 3631-3631/ru.grigoryev.rxjavatestdeleteafter D/custom: BINGO!

2019-06-25 22:25:36.873 3631-3631/ru.grigoryev.rxjavatestdeleteafter D/custom: KONGO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not with your `zip` implementation, but instead with the default behavior of a `PublishSubject`. But first, let's back up

### Hot and Cold Observables

In Rx, there are *two* types of `Obervables`, `hot` and `cold`. The most common type is a `cold` observable. A `cold` obervable will not start emitting values until `.subscribe()` has been called upon it.

```
val obs = Observable.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4);
obs.subscribe { print(it) }
// Prints 1, 2, 3, 4
```

A `hot` observable will emit values regardless if an observer has subscribed to it.

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
subject.onNext(1)
subject.onNext(2)
subject.subscribe { print(it) }
subject.onNext(3)
subject.onNext(4)

// Prints 3, 4
```

Notice how `1` and `2` where not printed. This is because a `PublishSubject` is a `hot` observable and emits `1` and `2` before it is subscribed to.

### Back to your Question

In your example, your publish subjects are emitting 1 and 2 *before* they are subscribed to. To see them `zipped` together, move your code around.

```
val currentSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
val maxSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

Log.d("custom", "BINGO!")

val zipped = Observables.zip(currentSubject, maxSubject) { current, max -> "current : $current, max : $max " }
zipped.subscribe(
    { Log.d("custom", it) },
    { Log.d("custom", "BONGO!") },
    { Log.d("custom", "KONGO!") }
)

currentSubject.onNext(1)
maxSubject.onNext(2)

currentSubject.onNext(1)
maxSubject.onNext(2)


currentSubject.onComplete()
maxSubject.onComplete()
```